# Replacing struct's unpack with native python

Tags: python, struct

I'm working on a project where I'm using SHA256, but due to the nature of [SGX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/software-guard-extensions.html?cid=sem&source=sa360&campid=2021_q1_dpg_us_dpgeng_dpgeng2_awa_text-link_brand_exact_cd_dcg-enterprise-sgx_3001996916_google_b2b_is_pbm&ad_group=brand_sgx_b2b3&intel_term=software%20guard%20extension&sa360id=43700058059108279&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAiAkJKCBhAyEiwAKQBCkuhMdMXc-lA2i_zodecl8EH0UlwgJUd3FA3wt0Sx6frIZgeRFu9iEhoCgTMQAvD_BwE), I cannot use `struct.unpack`, since it's a CPython implementation:

```
def _sha256_process(self, c):
        w = [0]*64
        print(c)
        print(struct.unpack('!16L', c))
        w[0:16] = struct.unpack('!16L', c)

        for i in range(16, 64):
            s0 = self._rotr(w[i-15], 7) ^ self._rotr(w[i-15], 18) ^ (w[i-15] >> 3)
            s1 = self._rotr(w[i-2], 17) ^ self._rotr(w[i-2], 19) ^ (w[i-2] >> 10)
            w[i] = (w[i-16] + s0 + w[i-7] + s1) & 0xFFFFFFFFL

        a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h = self._h

        for i in range(64):
            s0 = self._rotr(a, 2) ^ self._rotr(a, 13) ^ self._rotr(a, 22)
            maj = (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c)
            t2 = s0 + maj
            s1 = self._rotr(e, 6) ^ self._rotr(e, 11) ^ self._rotr(e, 25)
            ch = (e & f) ^ ((~e) & g)
            t1 = h + s1 + ch + self._k[i] + w[i]

            h = g
            g = f
            f = e
            e = (d + t1) & 0xFFFFFFFFL
            d = c
            c = b
            b = a
            a = (t1 + t2) & 0xFFFFFFFFL

        self._h = [(x+y) & 0xFFFFFFFFL for x,y in zip(self._h, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h])]
```

how can I replace `struct.unpack('!16L', c)` `c` is described below:

```
Nobody inspects?x
(1315922543, 1685659753, 1853059173, 1668576128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120)
e7a3f808cb0687fd3660e956a5df0f00e23edac5650769ec354ee670b658858c
Nobody inspects the spammish repetition?8
(1315922543, 1685659753, 1853059173, 1668576032, 1952998688, 1936744813, 1835627368, 544367984, 1702127988, 1768910464, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 312)
031edd7d41651593c5fe5c006fa5752b37fddff7bc4e843aa6af0c950f4b9406
Nobody inspects the spammish repetition?8
```

(1315922543, 1685659753, 1853059173, 1668576032, 1952998688, 1936744813, 1835627368, 544367984, 1702127988, 1768910464, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 312)
ok

The reason is I'm running the program in SGX, so CPython (which uses C-library) would cause the program to crash, in this case the use of struct.

Comment: "but due to the nature of SGX, I cannot use struct.unpack, since it's a CPython implementation" - ...why would that be a problem?

Comment: Because SGX doesn't support CPython... I actually have an implementation that works using struct but it causes the SGX program to crash, so I have to remove struct all together

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I suspect you're misusing the term "CPython", and anyway, other Python implementations should support `struct` too.

Comment: What does SGX stand for in this context?

Comment: I've updated the question... Here's a reference to SGX: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/software-guard-extensions.html?cid=sem&source=sa360&campid=2021_q1_dpg_us_dpgeng_dpgeng2_awa_text-link_brand_exact_cd_dcg-enterprise-sgx_3001996916_google_b2b_is_pbm&ad_group=brand_sgx_b2b3&intel_term=software+guard+extension&sa360id=43700058059108279&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAiAkJKCBhAyEiwAKQBCkuhMdMXc-lA2i_zodecl8EH0UlwgJUd3FA3wt0Sx6frIZgeRFu9iEhoCgTMQAvD_BwE

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I actually just want to replace the struct.unpack call with something native... that doesn't use any library

Comment: It's certainly possible to replace `struct.unpack` with pure Python code, but it's going to be less convenient and slower.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's fine being slower... security is the main concern of SGX. Could you post an implementation that replaces `struct.unpack`?

Comment: Is your SGX setup interfering with DLL loading? This question sounds like you need to fix the issue preventing you from using `struct` - you're going to have more issues like this, and not everything can be replaced with pure Python.

Comment: From a quick search, there are definitely people out there using plenty of Python C extensions with SGX. NumPy looks like a common example to show off, and that's a highly complex library with an extreme dependence on C extension code.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I understand, but I only needed a single line of code replaced: `struct.unpack('!16L', c)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `L` format (unsigned long) is very easy to construct from individual bytes.  Since you're trying to decode 16 of them, you'll have to do this 16 times in a loop using slicing.

```
def bytes_to_ulong(b):
    return ((b[0] & 0xff) << 24) | ((b[1] & 0xff) << 16) | ((b[2] & 0xff) << 8) | (b[3] & 0xff)
```

This is the version for network/big-endian order as indicated by the `!` in your format.

As an example of how you'd use slicing to extract 4 bytes at a time:

```
w[0:16] = [bytes_to_ulong(c[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, 16*4, 4)]
```

Comment: So Mark, `w[0:16] = [bytes_to_ulong(x) for x in c]`? Also, `c` is a string... so it shows as `Nobody inspects?x`

Comment: You'll have to do 4-byte-long slices, `c[0:4]`, `c[4:8]` and so on.

Comment: @cybertextron I've extended the answer to match your exact problem.  Since you were passing `c` directly to `struct.unpack` I expect it is a byte string, not a Unicode string.